# UITableViewCell Custom Layout and Border UIBubble

Tags: xcode, swift, uitableview

You probably used Messenger iOS App, it has a nice `UITableViewCell`.

I've googled everywhere so my search leaded me to `UIBubbleView`, but it's written entirely in Objective-C and unfortunately my background is with Swift, Also it has a lot of configuration e.g. Dynamic cell hight, supports images etc..

Anyway i have the design and i already done it in Illustrator but i was wondering how to replace the `Cell` with my designed `.png`

Any suggestions or tutorials i would be very thankful

Answer (score 0):

To answer the first part of your question, here is a link. This is a customized UI that works just like any other messaging apps. 
https://github.com/badoo/Chatto

For the second part of the question, this might be a useful solution.

For Cell

```
cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_normal.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0] ];  
cell.selectedBackgroundView =  [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_pressed.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0] ];
```

For Tableview

```
[mEditTableView setBackgroundView:nil];
[mEditTableView setBackgroundView:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"apple.png"]] ];
```

This is a delegate method, works fine as well.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell (UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{      
 if((indexPath.row)==0)  
   cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_normal.PNG"]]; //set image for cell 0

 if (indexPath.row==1)  
   cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:.8 green:.6 blue:.6 alpha:1]; //set color for cell 1

 tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"cloud.jpg"]]; //set image for UITableView

}
```